# How to capture input's type = 'text' clear event?

Tags: javascript, html, input, textbox

```html
<input type='text' onchange="reportAnswer(1, this.value);" 
onkeyup="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" 
oncut="this.onchange();" 
onclear = "this.onchange();" />
```

[image]

How to capture that change? This is IE11.

P.S. I added `onclear` handler because run out of ideas what to do.

Comment: What's providing that `[x]`? It's not something most browsers usually provide.

Comment: The basic idea is "clear input field value when some event happens. like click `[x]`". Take a look at the answer to question [How do I put a clear button inside my HTML text input box like the iPhone does?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803532/how-do-i-put-a-clear-button-inside-my-html-text-input-box-like-the-iphone-does)

Comment: @shawnzhu: The OP did say he just added `onclear` because he ran out of ideas.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - This is IE11.

Comment: @Kosmos: IE11 doesn't add that for me: http://jsbin.com/hicave/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't said what's providing that `[x]`, which is probably relevant, but the one event you haven't tried yet is `input` so: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/hicave/1)

```
<input type='text'
    onchange="reportAnswer(1, this.value);"
    onkeyup="this.onchange();"
    onpaste="this.onchange();"
    oncut="this.onchange();"
    oninput="this.onchange();" />
```

(No idea if it works, IE11 doesn't add that box for me on Windows 8.1.)

More likely, though, you need to hook into something provided by whatever it is that's providing that `[x]`.

Comment: `oninput` helped me :O Thank you. But don't know why IE11 do not add same thing for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the event of "oninput":

```
// Try to change value of the input below
<input id="input1" />

var input = document.getElementById("input1");
input.oninput = function(){alert("Value changed");}
```

Answer (score 0):

so its been 8 years but had the same problem and this was the first answer to show up found the answer in to this question here:
[How do you detect the clearing of a "search" HTML5 input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977023/how-do-you-detect-the-clearing-of-a-search-html5-input)

tl:dr

```
 $(some-input).on("search", function() { });
```

does the trick