# input type number and search combined

Tags: html, mobile

I am trying to get an input to be also for numbers (opening a number keyboard in mobile + up and down arrows) and making it like search type - adding "X" before the input if there is data inside it.

The problem is that can only choose one type - search or number...

How is it possible? even just to make a search type and added of number keyboard functionality is a good option.

Comment: Web Components - Custom Elements.

Comment: can you give an example please?

Comment: Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803532/how-do-i-put-a-clear-button-inside-my-html-text-input-box-like-the-iphone-does). And replace <input type="text"> with <input type="number">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to get an input to be also for numbers (opening a number
>   keyboard in mobile + up and down arrows) and making it like search
>   type - adding "X" before the input if there is data inside it

You have **two** options:

1. Have an `input` of `type=search` and define a `pattern` attribute to it. This way it will fire numeric keyboard on mobiles solving your first number requirement. However, it will not show up-down spinners. If you could do without the spinners, then this is the easiest option. Just markup the `input` like this:  `<input type="search" pattern="\d*" />`. The `pattern` `\d*` will force the validator to accept only digits. You can devise this regex as per your use-case.
2. You could use an `input` of `type=number`, which will solve both of your number problems. It will fire the numeric keyboard as well as show the spinners. This being a number type, will also automatically fire the validator if a non-numeric value is submitted. However, to make it behave like a `search` box, you will have to hack a *cross* into it using an extra `span` and some CSS. Moreover, you will need some Javascript to clear the `input` when the *cross* is clicked.

Here is a very crude example of both the options. Also, note that this may not be a truly cross-browser solution. For example, IE will happily ignore the `type=number` and actually show a *cross* at the right.

***Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/hgn7roje/***

***Demo Snippet***:

```js
$("span.closer").on("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName == 'SPAN') {
        $(this).children("input").val('');
    }    
});
```

```css
span.closer {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
span.closer::before {
    content: '×'; font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute; cursor: pointer;
    left: 4px; top: 2px;
}
span.closer:hover::before {
    color: #00f;
}
input[type=number] {
    padding-left: 16px;
    width: 220px;
}
input[type=number]:invalid {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
input[type=search] {
    width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label>Option 1: </label>
    <input type="search" pattern="\d*" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
<br />
<form>
    <label>Option 2: </label>
    <span class="closer"><input type="number" /></span>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: The first option won't work on chrome on mini ipad for example (it doesn't show the "X" in search type) - the 2nd option is something I can play with.

Comment: @dreamoki: Yup, these things cannot be relied upon cross-browser. There will be a few problems here and there. Anyway, this is just an idea.. you can tweak and tailor and further improvise based on your needs. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

The question has two independent parts to it:

1. Can the input element show a type of keyboard when input type=search?
2. Can the input element have a clear/cancel button shown when the input is not empty?

**Answer to part 1:**
The [inputmode='numeric'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode#numeric) attribute is available to augment the input type='search' element. Note that the inputmode attribute is available at all elements that are in contenteditable mode.

It started becoming available in 2017 and has support in all engines, except safari desktop. I have not checked it.

So the input element can simply be:

```html
<input type='search' inputmode='numeric' />
```

Which will show the numeric keyboard on mobile.

**Answer to part 2:**
My desktop browser Chrome 117 shows a clear button at the far right inside the input box as default behaviour. Which you can test using the snippet above.

Still the question was to have an X in front of the input.
There are numerous solutions here on stackoverflow about putting an icon somewhere in or around an input field. This is but 1 example.

Note that the concept is sound, but that I've misused the input type=reset button for my needs to create the functionality of clearing the search input. Oh, if only the ye olde reset button could be targeted...

```css
/* Hide the search cancel button in Chrome 117 & Safari? */
.search-input::-webkit-search-cancel-button
{  
  appearance: none;  
}

.search-input {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

/* Show the custom search cancel button when there is contents */
.search-clear-cancel {
  visibility: hidden;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
}
.search-clear-cancel:has(
  ~.search-input:not(:placeholder-shown)
)
{  
  visibility: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="reset" class="search-clear-cancel" value='x'/>
  <input class="search-input" type='search' inputmode='numeric' placeholder=" " />
</form>
```