# Put a button inside the text box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a form, with a button inside a text-box. I want that button to be inside the text-box. This is how I tried:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group required">
            <label for="PickList_Options" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Options</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4 buttonwrapper">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PickList_Options" name="PickList_Options" value='' />
                <button>GO</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="result" id="mydiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my css:

```
.buttonwrapper {
    display:inline-block;
}

input,
button {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:0;
}
```

But, the problem is, the Go button is placed below the text-box. What should I do to place it inside the text-box?

[image: Simple Image]

I want that "Go" button to be inside the text-box.

Comment: Absolute positioning is probably the best option here. (That is, if you really want to place the button _over_ the input field, in which case you will have to apply additional measures to keep it from obscuring text under it. The actual _best_ option would maybe rather be to simply have two elements next to each other, and put the rounded border around those two.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put a clear button inside my HTML text input box like the iPhone does?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803532/how-do-i-put-a-clear-button-inside-my-html-text-input-box-like-the-iphone-does)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```css
.buttonwrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

input{
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

button {
  margin-left: -50%;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label for="PickList_Options" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Options</label>

      <div class="col-sm-4 buttonwrapper">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PickList_Options" name="PickList_Options" value='' />
        <button>GO</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="result" id="mydiv"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

Please try this. Remove the `outline` for the `input` in `active` and `focus` state, and add a `border` for the input container.

Edit: Im adding the flex-box implementation as well.

1. Display `inline-block` implementation

```css
.input-container{
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
    display: inline-block;
}
.input-container input:focus, .input-container input:active {
    outline: none;
}
.input-container input {
    width: 80%;
    border: none;
}

.input-container button {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" class="input-field"/>
    <button class="input-button">Ok</button>
</div>
```

2. Display `flex` implementation

```css
.input-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.input-container input:focus, .input-container input:active {
    outline: none;
}
.input-container input {
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" class="input-field"/>
    <button class="input-button">Ok</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need give `position: absolute;` to the button & position it inside using `top`. Add these styles to your button

```
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/yVYVgW)

```css
.buttonwrapper {
    display:inline-block;
}

input,
button {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:0;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label for="PickList_Options" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Options</label>

      <div class="col-sm-4 buttonwrapper">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PickList_Options" name="PickList_Options" value='' />
        <button>GO</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="result" id="mydiv"></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use position:absolute feature here,

HTML

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group required">
                                    <label for="PickList_Options" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Options</label>

                                    <div class="col-sm-4 buttonwrapper">
                                    <div class="button-container">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PickList_Options" name="PickList_Options" value='' />
                                        <button>GO</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="result" id="mydiv"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

CSS

```
.button-container button {  line-height: 28px;  position: absolute;  right: 0;  top: 0;}
.button-container {position:relative;}
.button-container input {padding-right:40px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is put both the input field and the button in one container, you set that container to be positioned relatively and you set the button to be positioned absolutely. It's important that the container is positioned relatively, so to make sure the button stays within the input field.

Like so:

```
.buttonwrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

input,
button {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:0;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  /* Adjust these two to your liking */
  top: 6px;
  right: 3px;
}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label for="PickList_Options" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Options</label>

      <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="buttonwrapper">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PickList_Options" name="PickList_Options" value='' />
             <button>GO</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="result" id="mydiv"></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

for Simple purpose use this method,

Set fixed width for both text box and button.. for eg: text width is `200px`, button will be `40px` and add `margin-left:-40px`(based on your need) so it will be fixed between 160-200px of input text box..

```css
    .buttonwrapper {
            display:inline-block;
        }

        input,
        button {
            background-color:transparent;
            border:1 solid black;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group required">
                <label for="PickList_Options" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Options</label>

        

<div class="col-sm-4 buttonwrapper">
            <input type="text" style="width:200px" class="form-control" id="PickList_Options" name="PickList_Options" value='' />
            <button style="width:40px;margin-left: -43px">GO</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="result" id="mydiv"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Twitter Bootstrap does something like this very easily. They call it the [Input Group](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/).
If you are looking to do the same without the whole Bootstrap'ness, try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilgirraj/5bbmfcdj/1/).

Here's the markup

```
<span>
  <input type="text" value="Some text">
  <button onclick="alert('Hello!');">Click</button>
</span>
```

and the associated CSS

```
span {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
}

input,
button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: white;
  border-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are correct. But, there is a very simple way to achieve it. That is as follows:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group required">
                                    <label for="PickList_Options" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Options</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                          <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Add</button>
                                          </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                  
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

This does the trick. No need to write extra css properties. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.buttonwrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

input{
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

button {
  margin-left: 200px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label for="PickList_Options" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Options</label>

      <div class="col-sm-4 buttonwrapper">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PickList_Options" name="PickList_Options" value='' />
        <button>GO</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="result" id="mydiv"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to give a small description about your answer , refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer