# Adding clear button to search input box

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dynamic search input box and I would like to add a clear contents button but not sure how to do this. I have tried numerous bits of code that I have found on here but none seem to work. Here is the code I have.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});

<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search.." >
```

Comment: `$("#myInput").val("");`

Comment: check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803532/how-do-i-put-a-clear-button-inside-my-html-text-input-box-like-the-iphone-does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution

JQUERY

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      });

      $('#clear').click(function(){
        $('#myInput').val("");
          location.reload(); // To refresh the page
       })

    });
```

HTML

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

Comment: Your code works by clearing the input box but as this is a dynamic page search it doesn't reset the page. example if my page was full of words and I starting searching for a word, the more i type the less would be shown of the screen. If i click the clear button it doesn't reload the page

Comment: Oh that's easy, check my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery's **.val()** method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
  $("#clearButton").on("click", function() {

    $("#myInput").val("");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<button id="clearButton">
clear
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any Pure JavaScript or jQuery solution. You can do this by setting the `type` attribute of the Clear button to `reset`. Check the below snippet:

```html
<form action="http://">
    <input name="text">
    <input name="clear" type="reset" value="&#215;">
</form>
```

**Edit:**
To reload the page:

```html
<form action="http://">
    <input name="text">
    <input name="clear" type="reset" value="&#215;" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">
    // If we needed to pull the document from
    // the web-server again (such as where the document contents
    // change dynamically) we would pass the argument as 'true'.
</form>
```