# 'x' not displaying in Firefox inputs when using type="search" with custom CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been searching Stack Overflow answers for previous question but none seem to be helping for my Firefox issue.

I have all my inputs as `type="search"` and then some CSS to display a clear `button` which appears to be working in Edge, IE, Chrome but not in Firefox.

```css
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  border-radius: 50em;
  background: url(https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/svgs/solid/times-circle.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: contain;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="search"]:hover::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  opacity: .3;
  pointer-events: all;
}


/* Doesn't displays the 'X' when input 'Disabled' */

input[type="search"]:disabled::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control mand" type="search" />
```

**Screenshots**

*Chrome/IE/Edge*

[image]

*FF*

[image]

Chrome etc the 'x' is displayed `onhover` and `onfocus` but never in FF which I find peculiar as I'm using a Fontawesome image.

I have also tried just using

```
​input[type="search"] {
    background: transparent 
        url(https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/svgs/solid/times-circle.svg);
    background-position: 7px 7px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 2px 3px;
}​​​
```

but still nothing. I reference the above from another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form).

Comment: Is Firefox supposed to support all that `::-webkit-search-…` stuff, have you verified that?

Comment: Look here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-search-cancel-button

Comment: @mplungjan the input has to contain a value for it to display. The update you made to my post to allow the snippet is working for me

Comment: As the name suggests, `-webkit-search-cancel-button` is not a standard pseudo-element but a proprietary feature of the webkit browser engine. In general, you don't have such a high degree of control on widget styling, esp. on complex ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-search-cancel-button), Firefox does not support `::-webkit-search-cancel-button`, and it advises against its use use in serious websites. I advise you look at some of [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803532/how-do-i-put-a-clear-button-inside-my-html-text-input-box-like-the-iphone-does). The most-upvoted option doesen't appear to work in Firefox, but some of the ones below it appear to do just what you want. [This answer looks good, as it requires no JS.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65755630/10790516) It's not the nicest looking one on the page, but I'm sure you can sort that out.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your question.

*"I reference the above from another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917610/put-icon-inside-input-element-in-a-form)"*

You can put icons next to inputs like this. Thus, you can avoid browser support problems.

```html
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Add icon library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>

body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.input-container {
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.icon {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-right:none;
  min-width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:20px;
}

.input-field {
  width: 100%;
  font-size:20px;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-left:none;
  color:#000;
}
  
  .input-field::placeholder {
    color:#000;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" style="max-width:500px;margin:auto">
  <div class="input-container">
    <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
    <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="usrnm">
  </div>
  </form>
  </body>
```